# PermissionError with RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to use RandomizedSearchCV to tune the hyperparamers for a random forest, but I'm getting a PermissionError moments after running the code.

The initial run didn't have a PermissionError (it did throw an invalid handle error, however), but now I can't run the code at all. From what I've been able to figure out, WinError 5 is usually thrown when code is trying to format a drive without proper permissions, but as far as I know, RandomizedSearch isn't trying to alter anything. I have not tried to run as administrator yet, but getting access to that account would be difficult, so I'm trying to figure out if there is another way to resolve this. I'm running Python 3.7.

```py
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start=200, stop=2000, num=10)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num=11)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
bootstrap = [True, False]

random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}

print(random_grid)

constructed_data = pd.read_csv('Examples/Test_data.CSV')

forest = RandomForestClassifier()

forest.fit(train, train_labels)

forest_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=forest, param_distributions=random_grid, n_iter=100,
                                   cv=3, verbose=2, n_jobs=-1)

forest_random.fit(train, train_labels)
```

Expected: No errors and recommended hyperparameter values

Actual:

```py
Fitting 3 folds for each of 100 candidates, totalling 300 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
exception calling callback for <Future at 0x1013bc90 state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool>
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dalinar\PycharmProjects\visualizer\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\externals\loky\process_executor.py", line 391, in _process_worker
    call_item = call_queue.get(block=True, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\dalinar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 99, in get
    if not self._rlock.acquire(block, timeout):
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
'''
```

There are other exceptions thrown after this one, but the error above is the 'direct cause' of the others.

Comment: What if you run it as admin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue with the parallel processing, so try setting `n_jobs=1` when you create `RandomizedSearchCV()` object.

Additionally, you might want to have a look at [Parallalism in gridsearcCV is ending up with a permission error](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12546)